# Specify jwt token when fetch profile via "go tool pprof"

Tags: go, jwt, pprof

My api is protected via jwt, is it possible to specify a jwt token when fetch profile via `go tool pprof` ?

Currently, I have to config jwt middleware to bypass the `/debug/pprof` routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to pass a token via `go tool pprof` directly, but due to the fact that you can use `curl` to fetch the profile, there is a simple workaround:

```
$ curl -o profile.out https://host/debug/pprof -H 'X-Authorization: $TOKEN'
$ go tool pprof profile.out
```

Comment: Cool, this works. BTW, the request will wait 30 seconds by default while the profile is being generated. `wget` works similarly.

Comment: Yes, but you can control the time of collecting data through "seconds" parameter, eg.: to reduce the time to 5 seconds: `curl -o profile.out https://host/debug/pprof?seconds=5 -X 'X-Authorization: $TOKEN'`

Comment: The idea works but you should specify the header with the `-H` flag to `curl` not `-X`. Like this: 
`$ curl -o profile.out https://host/debug/pprof -H 'X-Authorization: $TOKEN'`

Comment: @ezileli you're absolutely right, thanks for pointing out